# htaccess "DirectoryIndex disabled" with <Directory "."> don't work?

Tags: .htaccess

The `DirectoryIndex`, specially with `DirectoryIndex disabled`, don't work by me when i use `<Directory ".">`.

Internal Server Error:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
<Directory ".">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex indeks.html
    DirectoryIndex indice.html
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Internal Server Error:

```
#<IfModule mod_dir.c>
<Directory ".">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex indeks.html
    DirectoryIndex indice.html
</Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
#<Directory ".">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex indeks.html
    DirectoryIndex indice.html
#</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Works fine:

```
#<IfModule mod_dir.c>
#<Directory ".">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex indeks.html
    DirectoryIndex indice.html
#</Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Is this only a problem for me? I have only a webhost on a shared virtual server. What could be the problem?

EDIT: apache 2.4

Comment: `Directory` directive is only supported in `server.config` and `vartul host` context. You can not use it in htaccess file.

Comment: And what is `<Directory ".">` meant to relate to?

Comment: @arkascha, i like your question ;)

Comment: Please note that the message "Internal Server Error" is just what the http server hands out to untrusted clients. That does not tell you anything. You need to take a look into the http server's error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the actual issue is. _You cannot develop a web application without monitoring that file..._